# Mean of top two realizations when one of them is known (order statistics)

Tags: means, order-statistics

suppose that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are independently drawn according to a CDF $F$.

I understand the mean of highest or second highest value can be found using the order statistics.

My question is if we know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the top two highest values and if we know the exact value of $x_2$, then what would be the expected value of $x_1$?

Any hint or help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\mathsf P(X_1\le x_1)=F(x_1)^3$, thus for $x_1\ge x_2$

$$
\mathsf P(X_1\le x_1\mid X_2=x_2)=\mathsf P(X_1\le x_1\mid X_1\ge x_2)=\frac{F(x_1)^3-F(x_2)^3}{1-F(x_2)^3}
$$

and thus

$$
\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2=x_2)=x_2+\int_{x_2}^\infty\left(1-\mathrm P(X_1\le x_1\mid X_2=x_2)\right)\mathrm dx_1=x_2+\int_{x_2}^\infty\frac{1-F(x_1)^3}{1-F(x_2)^3}\,\mathrm dx_1\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks, @joriki. shouldn't we also think about the cases where $x_1\leq x_2$?

Comment: @Andeanlll: I'm sorry, I think I misread the question. I read "order statistics" and then I read "if we know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the top two highest values" and somehow I put that together and inferred that they're the top two highest values in that order :-) I'll correct the answer.